# How can convert 24:00 to 00:00 in javascript without AM/PM

Tags: javascript

```js
   {value.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
              hour: 'numeric',
              minute: '2-digit',
              hour12: false,
            })}
```

Hi, I want show time value looks like 00:00 when 24:00 without AM/PM function.

is there anyway can show them ?

Comment: Are you trying to convert 24hr time to 12hr time?

Comment: yes, but my pm does not want show time looks like AM 1:00

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want, but if you use a different locale (like `en-UK` and use `hour : '2-digit'` you'll get `00:00` instead of `24:00`.